# How can I programmatically format text in visio shapes (color, size, font)?

Tags: c#, format, vsto, visio, shapesheet

I can change the font, color, size of characters in the shape. But only for rows that already exist in the VisSectionIndices.visSectionCharacter of shapesheet.

I cant create new rows for this section and cant change the number of characters for each formatting.

Any solution will suit me. Any hack, any idea.

I already broke my head, I don't know how to approach this.

How do I change the color of the text inside one shape? (For example black green red?)

Comment: Welcome to So. See [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow. You could check some visio book, like "Developing Visio Solutions" free microsoft book, it discusses these subjects.

There is also a great Visio forum, http://visguy.com/vgforum/ where you can find lots of visio-specific question answered out of the box. Russian visio related forum forum: https://visio.getbb.ru/

Also, you can always use **macro recorder** to generate the code (I mean, you turn on the recording, do the action manually, and get the generated code in the VBA IDE)

Anyways. You can use `shape.Characters` to modify style of a text fragment. Like this:

```vb
    Set shp = ActivePage.DrawRectangle(0, 0, 1, 1)
    
    Set chars = shp.Characters
    chars.Text = "Something  with Red Text"

    chars.Begin = 10
    chars.End = 19
    chars.CharProps(visCharacterColor) = 2
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Без проблем :D But actually there here it's better to use English..there is a localized version ("stackoverflow на русском") there it's fine. If are fine with the answer you can accept it, to show that it's OK.